# How to re-create /tmp/mysql.sock?

Tags: mysql

Have a pretty simple problem, I have accidentally deleted /tmp/mysql.sock file

Now I can not use mysqladmin or anything

How can I recreate this file?

Before I asking this question I have looked at related questions, but I could not find info that I needed.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your mysql.sock is inside /tmp/? I think usually this is located in /home/mysql or under the data directory (/var/lib/mysql/). You may as well check if it is still available there.

If it is, rather than restarting the daemon, you can just create a softlink to /tmp:

```
ln -s /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/
```

Answer (score 7):

Restart mysqld.

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

or

```
/sbin/service mysql restart
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have installed MySQL from source :(

Comment: How do you start it? You can have an init script even if you install from source. If you don't have one, just `killall mysqld` and restart it however you normally do.

Comment: That gave `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)` and `mysql: unrecognized service`

Comment: @Magne Then just try: `/etc/init.d/mysql start`

Comment: I got it working. Since I was on CentOS, I had to write `mysqld` instead of `mysql`. So it became: `/etc/init.d/mysqld stop` and `/etc/init.d/mysqld start`

Answer (score 2):

Just restart your MySQL daemon.

Answer (score 1):

You can't recreate it since it's a named socket. As others have said, you must restart mysqld.

Answer (score 0):

edited my.cnf to reflect this (replacing "socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock" with "socket = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock")

Comment: He didn't move it, he deleted the socket. he just needs MySQL to recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

You may see this even after starting mysqld because the process is still setting up. I've seen it with Innodb taking several minutes, can be even longer, to restore, and during that time, there will be no socket file. Check your Mysql error log to see if there's activity like this taking place (`tail -f /var/log/mysql.err`).