# MySQL configuration issue Error ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, opensuse

I recently installed OpenSuse11.1 and tried configuring mysql with it however after installation I was not even able to start it off

I got the following error

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

As suggested in one of the forums I enabled the `skip-networking` option in `/etc/my.cnf` which did not help

I also tried binding it to the address using `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` in the same `/etc/my.cnf`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. A after following the above steps I need to run rcmysql wwhich would configure it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check:

```
/var/log/mysql.err
/var/log/mysql.log
```

for errors

2) Check if /var partition is not full

Comment: The log files do not exist
and my var folder is under root so its not full again

Answer (score -2):

Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Check mysql.sock file is available or not it will be stored in following path
 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
 If mysql.sock file missing create mysql.sock and change ownership to mysql:msql to that      file.Generally mysql.sock will create automatically when mysql server restart. If not create it.

The above procedure  is for ubuntu in opensuse check where the mysql.sock file is stored and follow above that i mentioned.

Comment: [You can't create `mysqld.sock` since it's a named socket. As others have said, you must restart mysqld](http://serverfault.com/a/73713/218590)

Comment: @masegaloeh The same error happend to me once and i fixed itby following  create mysqld.sock  check this [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXjJRrbKjp0)

Comment: **You don't need create mysqld.sock**, of course you still create the directory where the socket reside i.e `mkdir /var/run/mysql`.

Comment: @masegaloeh whatever but the solutions works anyway thank's for letting me know.